# microsoft bot (created with SDK for nlp with dispatch) returns 401 unauthorized error after deploying to Azure

Tags: azure, botframework

I created a bot with Microsoft bot framework by downloading code from github for nlp-with-dispatch. It is working fine in my local machine, but however, after deploying it to azure, I am gettting 401 unauthorized error both in webchat and directline channels.

Comment: Most probably it means precisely what is says. Will ou share details?

Comment: Have you added your Microsoft App Id and Microsoft App Password in your code? (Usually in appsettings.json)

Comment: You will have to ensure that you have specified the correct app ID and password for your bot in the application settings on azure as well as in your bot code(appsettings.json or .env file). Also,check if you have specified the correct messaging endpoint in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the App ID and Password are correct in your code / app settings. 
This article provides some additional troubleshooting steps for debugging authentication issues.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps you can follow to debug your bot and narrow down on the cause:

- Ensure that you have specified the correct Microsoft AppId and passowrd in the application settings for your bot on Azure as well as your bot code(appsettings.json or .env file).
  [image]
- Go to the Settings blade of your bot on Azure and double check if you have specified the correct messaging endpoint.
  [image]
- Try creating a  new web app bot on Azure and then publish the bot to the corresponding web app that you specified as the messaging endpoint and test and see if the newly created bot works or not.

Additionally, you can go through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) for the troubleshooting steps in detail.

Hope this helps.